# Node JS loading secrets on a "pre" task and updating the environment variables for the main task

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, environment-variables

I have many services written in Node and loading secrets on startup has always been a problem for me.

I believe that when a service starts up, it should have every piece of configuration/secret ready for it beforehand.

- Static configurations are easy (environment variables, usually via `.env` file).
- Secrets? More complex if the infra hosting you doesn't support that.

Luckily, I've found that in Node, whatever script we add to the `package.json` file can have `pre` and/or `post` scripts as well.
So it comes in very handy, as I can:

1. have a reusable code that loaded secrets from somewhere
2. persists the values in the environment variables
3. before starting up the main script

The difficulty is that I'm unable to persist environment variables and have them available on the next process.

I wonder if that's a limitation (in Linux) or there's some way that I have missed.

Writing the secrets to a file to be read by the main process is unacceptable.

Comment: Can't you just write your secrets to a file when you encrypt them beforehand and decrypt them on load?

Comment: I prefer not to. Wondering if there's a solution for the environment variables